# Не создаётся панель в jPlayer

Tags: jquery

Юзаю jPlayer для воспроизведения музыки на странице. Сам плэер инициализируется, но панели нет.

```
<link type="text/css" href="skin/jplayer.blue.monday.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jPlayer/jquery.jplayer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jPlayer/add-on/jquery.jplayer.inspector.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
        ready: function (event) {
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                mp3:"music/Sing_For_The_Moment.mp3",
            });
        },
        swfPath: "jPlayer/Jplayer.swf",
        supplied: "mp3",
        wmode: "window"
    });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="jquery_jplayer_1"></div>
```

Comment: походу руками и нужно, потому что в скрипте я ничё подобного не нашёл(

Answer (score 1):

у меня когда-то была в swfPath загвоздка, присмотрись к этой строчки, напр. jplayer.swf и jPlayer.swf может быть две разные вещи.

Comment: вроде всё ок(

добавил панель руками, но мне кажется скрипт сам должен её создать)

Comment: должен, иначе никак, то что вы код привели это хорошо, но плеер такая штука что тут без серверной части сложно чем-то помочь, в крайнем случае на офсайте плеера должна быть документация и F.A.Q. на сколько я помню.